# Linear independence proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that
1. One vector is linearly independent if and only if it is not the zero vector.
Let $S = \{\mathbf{0},v_1, \ldots,v_n\}$ be a set of vectors. Then
\begin{equation*}
1\times \mathbf{0}+0\times v_1+0\times v_2+\ldots+o\times v_n = 0
\end{equation*}
shows that the zero vector can be written as a nontrivial linear combination of the vectors in $S$. So any one vector can't be linearly independent unless it is the zero vector.
2. Two vectors are linearly independent if and only if one is not a scalar multiple of the other.
3. Three vectors are linearly independent if and only if one is not a linear combination of the other two.
Not sure on the last two. Thanks!

Comment: What you showed is that any set of vectors containing the zero vector cannot be a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 0):

- $1$ says, $\{x\}$ is independent $\iff$ $x \neq 0$

Proof:

$$\{x\} \;\text{is dependent} \iff \exists a \neq 0 \ni ax=0 \iff x=a^{-1}0=0$$

Since $a \neq 0, a^{-1}$ exists. so the last multiplication is meaningfull!

- $2$ says, $\{x,y\}$ is dependent $\iff$ $x=k y$ for some $k$

Proof:

$\implies$: Assume $\{x,y\}$ is dependent. Then there exists $a,b$ such that not both zero, and $ax+by=0$. Assume $a \neq 0$. Then $x=-(\frac{b}{a})
y=ky$ where $k=-b/a$

$\impliedby$: If $x=ky$, then $\color{red}1 \cdot x-\color{red}ky=0$, concluding $\{x,y\}$ is dependent

Third one is also easy, so do yourself!

Comment: Great thanks. Just one question what do you mean by the last multiplication being meaningful?

Comment: Multiply both sides of $ax=0$ by $a^{-1}$ to get $x=0$

Comment: So the proof for the one vector case involves showing that $x$ is linearly dependent if and only if $x=0$?

Comment: We will show that one vector $\{x\}$ is linearly dependent (not linearly independent) if and only if it is the zero vector. $\{x\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if there exists an $a\neq 0$ such that $ax = 0$. Multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ gives $a^{-1}ax = a^{-1}0 = 0$. Since $a\neq 0$, we must have $x = 0$ and we are done. Is this another way to show it (it is actually what is mentioned above)?